# Implementing Azure AD Single Sign On to an Angular 6 single page application

Tags: angular6, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I was wondering if implementing Azure AD SSO on a SPA is possible and if anyone knows of any good (step by step?) guide for this?

What i need is mostly the back end code implementation but i full step by step guide would be perfect.

I know Microsoft has this page with some examples but i'm not sure if they're compatible with angular 6 specifically:

[Azure Active Directory code samples (v1.0 endpoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code)

So any good suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Microsoft's official library for providing support for Angular 4-5. I think this maybe your best example of how to implement the same for Angular 6.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular

You can also try the OpenID connect route with this library:  https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

Comment: Ahh, Thank you very much @Jamie! I will definitely try this one out.

Comment: @John, Did you try it? Has it worked? I'm trying to work with SSO, but I can not get any results. Some information will be fantastic :) Thanks

Comment: Hi sorry for the late answer, Yeah we tried the "microsoft-adal-angular6" packages and if i remember correctly it worked pretty much flawlessly. Thanks a lot for the answer and also your persistence. I'll mark this ans the answer.

I got side-tacked on this part of the project so i don't remember if my colleagues tried the packages above. but what i gathered information-wise was that the earlier angular packages should work just as microsoft have specified.